# Can someone explain to me the pack() function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, binary, pack

I would like to know more about the `pack()` function in PHP: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

I know it packs data into binary, but I'm not sure what all those `v V n N c C` mean and I was wondering if someone could be so kind as to give me a practical demonstration when to use which formats?

The online documentation, for a change, lacks of information, in my opinion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those represent how you want the data you are packing to be represented in binary format:

so

`$bin = pack("v", 1);  =>  0000000000000001`   (16bit)

where

`$bin = pack("V", 1)   => 00000000000000000000000000000001`   (32 bit)

It tells pack how you want the data represented in the binary data.
The code below will demonstrate this.  Note that you can unpack with a different
format from what you packed the data as.

```
<?php

$bin = pack("S", 65535);
$ray = unpack("S", $bin);
echo "UNSIGNED SHORT VAL = ", $ray[1], "\n";

$bin = pack("S", 65536);
$ray = unpack("S", $bin);
echo "OVERFLOW USHORT VAL = ", $ray[1], "\n";

$bin = pack("V", 65536);
$ray = unpack("V", $bin);
echo "SAME AS ABOVE BUT WITH ULONG VAL = ", $ray[1], "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Sir, may i know more about the repeaters? what is the expected functionality of  a repeater

Answer (score 12):

As noted in the php documentation for pack, the function is borrowed from Perl's pack function.

Take a look at [Perl's documentation for pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), specifically the examples section at the very bottom of the page.  PHP's pack does not implement all the formats, but Perl's documentation for the function does a better job of providing examples and explaining each format.